# Showing product size and color in magento checkout success page

Tags: php, magento

Actually just want to show product attribute on magento checkout success page

Currently just found it,

```
foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item) {  

     echo '<div class="line"><p class="name">Product:' . $item->getName() . '</p>';  
     echo '<p class="price">' . Mage::helper("core")->currency($item->getPrice()) . '</p>';  
     echo '<p class="qty">' . round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0) . '</p>';  

}
```

and need for the size and color, any suggestion .. thanks

Comment: What type of product using?? configurbale

Comment: yep configurable @amit-bera

Answer (score 0):

If ,you using Configurable then try this.you need load simple product by sku.
Please

```
    foreach ($order_details->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
.
      $item->getProduct();// is give configurable product 
      $item->getSku(); // give  simple product sku,of  order item
      $_product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $item->getSku());
      $_product1->getColor();
      $_product1->getSize();

    }
```

If you used `getAllItems` then put condition `if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {`